# Unable to install Docker on Azure VM

Tags: azure, docker

I have an Azure VM on which I am trying to install docker. The installation proceeds smoothly. When I try to run the hello world example of docker, I get this error `docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.`

This is the [procedure](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1) I followed. I have run the docker with sudo. I can't figure out what is causing the problem. Any helps on figuring out this would be much appreciated. I have scoured the internet on fixing this issue. Nothing has worked. I have uninstalled docker completely, and reinstalled it again. Nothing seems to work.

EDIT: I have narrowed down the problem to the fact that the daemon has to be started manually. How do I ensure the daemon starts running as soon as the machine is up or docker is started? Running `sudo dockerd` and then running `docker run hello-world` seems to work.

Comment: `sudo docker version`?

Comment: Version:           18.09.0
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        4d60db4
 Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:48:57 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run docker commands as a non-root user.

To achieve that you have to add your user to the `docker` group, but bear in mind that this can be a security risk, as this group grants `root` equivalent privileges.

You can find the detailed configuration steps in the [post-installation for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) and information about the risks in the [Docker daemon attack surface](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) description

Comment: I thought running the command with `sudo` would help. Seems like I was wrong. I will try out the link you pointed to

Comment: if you run your docker commands with `sudo`, you shouldn't need to change anything to the group settings. What I described is mainly if you want to run the commands with a non-root user.

Comment: Aah, I missed that. Thanks for bringing it to my notice. Starting the daemon manually and then running `sudo docker run hello-world` works. However, once I stop the manually started daemon and try running the hello world example, the error pops up again.

Comment: When you stop your manually started daemon, you have to start the `service` which is supposed to be started on boot. Try restarting your machine to test if the service starts properly on boot, and then test your commands again.

Comment: Same problem. `sudo service docker start` throws the following error. `Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` Running it manually seems to work.

Comment: Try with `sudo systemctl start docker`

Comment: @Raghuram Have a check as the error shows. Run "`journalctl -xe`" and provide the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you daemon isnt running - which VM did you create? Linux based? if so there are few thing regarding to the daemon you must do in order to make the docker work - You need to configure your "daemon.json" or create one if you dont have - Here's the docker documentation that might help you with it - 
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/

Best of luck!

Comment: Yes it is a Linux based VM. Ubuntu 16.04 to be precise. I will check out the link

Comment: I just looked at the link that you shared. I started the daemon manually through `sudo dockerd` and then ran `sudo docker run hello-world`. That worked. However, stopping the manually started daemon process and then running `sudo docker run hello-world` throws up the same error. So, the daemon process is not starting automatically.